# Alternative to sqlite3_get_table

Tags: c++, visual-c++, select, sqlite

I have a function called isadded() and it was the cause of my program crashing. I run debugdiag and found this

```
Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3   Source 
ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+df     00001484     00000002     00000000    
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+a8     09e10c08     006310a5     09e10c08    
sqlite3!sqlite3_mutex_leave+17b     09caf370     0c81d9c8     0063d240    
sqlite3!sqlite3_get_table+99     09caf370     0c81d9c8     0c81d9bc    
OServHandler!COServHandler::isAdded+17f     059a6fd8     0c8272e0     00000006    
OServHandler!COServHandler::getHierarchy+ba7     0c940020     00008000     6009fb27    
AdminConsoleInterface!CAdminConsoleInterface::handleConnection+178     00001254     00000000     00000000    
AdminConsoleInterface!CAdminConsoleInterface::setOServHandler+33     008c5cd0     0250e9c8     00000000
```

So, the line where it errs out is sqlite3_get_table().

```
sprintf_s(query,1024,"SELECT * FROM OServs WHERE oservname = '%s' ;", cOServID);
cout<<query<<endl;
rc = sqlite3_get_table(db, query, &results, &nrow, &ncol, &zErrMsg);
```

Basically I am trying to see if a particular variable is already added in the database. Is there any alternative to this function since it seems to crash? I remember reading that this function was deprecated, but don't know what the alternative is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a handful of commands to replace `sqlite3_get_table`.  Here is the [basic c/c++ intro](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) tutorial that explains the process.  You have to do more work, but there is much more control.

Each one is very well documented in the function section of the [sqlite3 reference](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html).

Update:

As an alternative, you can use sqlite3_exec, it is a bit less intense.  Here is a small code sample that I found.

http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/code/simplesqlite3.c.html

Comment: Is there like a easier way to see if record just exists in the database. Does it make sense to just keep these records in a flat file instead of a db? It is just a two column table, and I want to see if record exists or not.

Comment: Why is it so hard to find a decent code example showing how to run a query and access the results? This is so irritating. The website just says "For queries, extract results by calling sqlite3_column() in between two calls to sqlite3_step()."

Comment: @roymustang86 I added another link with an example.  Sometimes is difficult to search for things you don't know much about.  To find that I typed `c++ sqlite3_exec example` and found that on the first page.