# How to find str in sql table

Tags: c++, sqlite, embedded-linux

The code simply needs to let the caller know if `path` is in the table or not.
The c++ code below does this correctly using `select count(*)` and `sqlite3_get_table` but only for a short while, then dies.
There are apparently issues with sqlite3_get_table.
There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402720/alternative-to-sqlite3-get-table) but I don't see how to apply this answer to my problem.
I have read the sqlite docs and gone through the sqlite tutorial.
I have used sqlite3_exec to initialize the db and insert new records but again, do not see how to write a robust c++ method that simply returns a bool if it finds or does not find a match in the table. As I said, the code below works, but not for more than a few hundred calls. Shouldn't this be one of the simplest things to do with a database? Are there any simple examples of how to do this or suggestions as to the best way to solve this problem?

```
bool ifFound(string path) {
    if (turn_off) return false;
    char **result;
    int nrow = 0; // Number of result rows
    int ncol = 0; // Number of result columns
    char * zErrMsg = 0; // Error message
    if (SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_open(database_path.c_str(), &db)) {
        coutError(__FILE__, __LINE__, "Can't open database " + database_path);
        return false;
    }
    int count = 0;
    string sqlCommand = "select count(*) from my_table where path='"+path+"'";
    if (SQLITE_OK == 
        sqlite3_get_table(db, sqlCommand.c_str(),&result,&nrow,&ncol,&zErrMsg)) 
        count = atoi(result[ncol]);
    else coutError(__FILE__, __LINE__, sqlCommand + " " + zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free_table(result);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return (count != 0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "die"?

Comment: @CL. by `die` I mean the process (embedded-linux) just goes away, don't know who kills it or why. But the code runs without issue when `ifFound` is stubbed which makes it fairly certain that the issue is with `sqlite3_get_table.`

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with this function. Can't you run your program with a debugger, or on a desktop?

Comment: Yes. I know - the function actually works just not for very long.

Comment: So I added a callback and a global variable to hold the match count. I'll post the code in an answer. After it runs well for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get rid of sqlite3_get_table is to replace it with sqlite3_exec, a callback to handle the query result, and a global variable to hold the count.

```
static int pathFound = 0;
int sqlCallback(void *p, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    pathFound = atoi(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
void checkPath(string path) {
    string sqlCommand = "select count(*) from m_table where path='"+path+"'";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlCommand.c_str(), sqlCallback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if (SQLITE_OK != rc) {
        coutError(__FILE__, __LINE__, sqlCommand + "\n" + zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    if (0 == pathFound) doInsert(path);
}
```